# Using IF statement on multiple strings [Batch]

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am writing software to scan through predetermined services and start them if they are stopped. Unfortunately some of the service names have spaces so if i do this:

```
for %%a in (MSSQLSERVER,SQLSERVERAGENT,Cardinal SPD Delivery Package Service,AuthenticationServiceHost,CommunicationService,CqiProcessorService,IISADMIN,MobileAutmationAgentService,MSMQ) do (
```

What happens is, it treats the Cardinal SPD Delivery package as three separate services instead of one when i do

```
net start "%%a"
```

for example.
The alternative that I found that works is putting the services in  a text file and doing

```
for /f %%a in (services.txt) do(
```

But I would prefer to do it the first method since it's a lot cleaner. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either double quote all services names and don't quote `%%a` in the call:

```
for %%a in ("MSSQLSERVER","SQLSERVERAGENT","Cardinal SPD Delivery Package Service","AuthenticationServiceHost","CommunicationService","CqiProcessorService","IISADMIN","MobileAutmationAgentService","MSMQ") do (
net start %%a
)
```

Or double quote only multiple words and remove the quotes from `%%a` when you call it:

```
for %%a in (MSSQLSERVER,SQLSERVERAGENT,"Cardinal SPD Delivery Package Service",AuthenticationServiceHost,CommunicationService,CqiProcessorService,IISADMIN,MobileAutmationAgentService,MSMQ) do (
net start %%~a
)
```

Comment: The second way does not work for me because before I start the service i do `net start |find/i "%%a"` , if I just quote the multiple word services, it won't work because it will doublequote.

I tried the first one and I get: 

    `NET START   | FIND/i ""Cardinal SPD Delivery Package Service""      1>nul
     call :startService
    )
    File not found - CARDINAL
    File not found - SPD
    File not found - DELIVERY
    File not found - PACKAGE
    File not found - SERVICE`

Comment: try to use the first one with `net start |find/i %%a` (remove the quotes). Works for me with Win7

Comment: @bill the services.txt method may seem less neat but it is highly structured, reliable, and robust since you can handle large lists, spaces without problem, it's flexible, and you can easily see every service name you're working with. I've used it for years because it's actually easier in the end for this task.

Comment: Thank you Lizz, I think I will agree. Just having a lot of headache getting the first method working Properly. Thank you again for everyone's help :)